# pyobdc Update query executes successfully but doesnt update database

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I have a problem with executing an MS SQL Update query with pyodbc. The query executes successfully but the database entries are not being updated. Running the same query in sql management studio return an successfull update of over 800 entries.
What am I doing wrong?

```
import pyodbc
    
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                          'Server=SERVER2020;'
                          'Database=Auftragsmanagement;'
                          'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
    
sql_einkaufspreis_in_artikel_schreiben = "UPDATE dbo.Artikel " \
                                            "SET Artikel.Einkaufspreis = t.Einkaufspreis " \
                                            "from dbo.Artikel A " \
                                            "Inner Join " \
                                            "(select a.id, " \
                                                "(sum(IIF(e.kategorie NOT IN (7, 10), r.menge*IIF(a.NutzeManuellenPreisInKalkulation = 1 AND r.manuellerPreis != 0, r.manuellerPreis, IIF(t.preis IS NOT NULL,  t.preis/e.Berechnungsmenge, e.preis/e.Berechnungsmenge))/(1-a.Kalkulation_Verlust/100), 0))/" \
                                                "sum(IIF(e.kategorie NOT IN (7, 10, 3, 26), r.menge, 0))+" \
                                                "sum(IIF(e.kategorie IN (7, 10), r.menge*IIF(a.NutzeManuellenPreisInKalkulation = 1 AND r.manuellerPreis != 0, r.manuellerPreis, IIF(t.preis IS NOT NULL, t.preis/e.Berechnungsmenge, e.preis/e.Berechnungsmenge)), 0)))*a.Kalkulationsgewicht AS Einkaufspreis " \
                                            "from dbo.Artikel A " \
                                            "INNER JOIN dbo.Rezeptur R ON R.Artikel = a.id " \
                                            "INNER JOIN dbo.Einkaufsartikel E ON r.einkaufsartikel = e.id " \
                                            "INNER JOIN dbo.Lieferant L ON l.id = e.lieferant " \
                                            "LEFT JOIN dbo.EinkaufsartikelMapping EPM ON epm.Einkaufsartikel = e.ID " \
                                            "LEFT JOIN dbo.EinkaufsartikelSpezifikation EP ON ep.id = epm.EinkaufsartikelSpezifikation " \
                                            "FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT ep.id, e.Preis, e.LetzteLieferung " \
                                                            "FROM (" \
                                                                "SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EP.ID ORDER BY e.LetzteLieferung DESC) AS LASTORDER, e.id " \
                                                                "FROM dbo.Einkaufsartikel E, dbo.EinkaufsartikelSpezifikation EP, dbo.EinkaufsartikelMapping EPM " \
                                                                "WHERE e.id = epm.Einkaufsartikel and ep.id = epm.EinkaufsartikelSpezifikation) as list, dbo.Einkaufsartikel E " \
                                                            "INNER JOIN dbo.EinkaufsartikelMapping EPM ON e.id = epm.Einkaufsartikel " \
                                                            "INNER JOIN dbo.EinkaufsartikelSpezifikation EP ON epm.EinkaufsartikelSpezifikation = ep.ID " \
                                                            "where list.ID = e.ID and list.LASTORDER <= 1 " \
                                                            "GROUP BY ep.id, e.LetzteLieferung, e.Preis) t ON t.ID = ep.ID " \
                                            "where a.kategorie != 99 and a.IstKalkuliert = 1 and a.Gelöscht = 0 " \
                                            "group by a.id, a.Kalkulationsgewicht) t ON t.id = a.ID"
    
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql_einkaufspreis_in_artikel_schreiben)
cursor.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Are there any limitations in pyodbc when trying to update rows?

`cursor.rowcount` returns 865 rows. Why does is return an value but doesn't update.

### EDIT

Adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the beginning of the query solves the problem, but then I won't have the number of affected rows. Is there another solution for that?

Comment: Shot in the dark from someone who's not a Python programmer: What happens of you do a conn.commit() instead of (or in addition to) a cursor.commit()?

Comment: @TN - I was thinking the same thing but according to the [pyodbc documentation](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#commit) calling `Cursor.commit()` is "no different than calling commit on the connection".

Comment: Please do yourself a favour and use a multi-line string, then format the SQL properly. It's absolutely unreadable. Given the number of joins, how do you know it's even getting any rows to update? A `full join` is particularly suspect

Comment: @Charlieface I have edited the question and formated the SQL for better readability. The statement works fine in SQL Management studio and is updating the rows (865 rows affected, thereof 18 were updated).
I nearly had the same issue in php with sqlsrv_query. There the query is only working when calling sqlsrv_query twice. Probably there are any limitations when trying to update several rows at once?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with a very simple example, get that working, and then you can move on to more complex examples. What you have now is pretty complex.

See the links below for more details.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

https://datatofish.com/import-csv-sql-server-python/

https://www.dataquest.io/blog/sql-insert-tutorial/

Comment: Actually, I already have some select and insert python programs running successfully. Only this update statement doesn't update the rows even though it's not giving an error.
I could change it into a sql query and then updating row by row using a loop but this would take so much longer to complete.
The given sql statement completes in sql management studio in less than a second.